# ZeroDivisionError in numpy.average

Tags: numpy, average, weighted-average

I am calculating a weighted average value on numpy:

```
np.average(df['column1'], weights=df['column2'])
```

I received this error: `Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized`

Is there an argument I can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

can you try:

```
(df['column1'].values*df['column2'].values).sum()/df['column2'].sum()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try `numpy.ma.average()` instead. See [reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.average.html#numpy.ma.average).